# Rename a file column name in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a file with poor naming convention I would like to clean up before using in `Azure` `Synapse`. Is it possible to rename the column in the `with` block?

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'path_to_file.csv'
    FORMAT = 'CSV'
    PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    FIRSTROW = 2)
    WITH (
        [ORDER ID] varchar(50)
    ) as rows
```

I could use an alias in the `select` but was hoping to clean it up before that.

`SELECT [ORDER ID] as order_id`

And I could wrap this in a view - just was hoping there's a way to rename earlier.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use a Data Flow in a pipeline to reproduce the file with good headers, I think you are stuck with the SELECT ... AS ... approach. I think if you use FIRSTROW = 2 instead of HEADER_ROW = TRUE (as in this example), the column names would actually be C1, C2, C3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to rename columns in `WITH` block; the name you provide there will override the column name read from the file (even with `HEADER_ROW` set to `TRUE`.

There's a caveat though. You will have to either provide names for ***all*** of your columns:

```
    SELECT TOP 10  *  
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (BULK 'path_to_file.csv',  
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        HEADER_ROW = true)
    WITH
    (   
        your_column_name_1 varchar(50)
        ...
        your_column_name_N varchar(50)
    ) 
    AS rows
```

...or pick the ones you want to keep and/or rename using their *ordinal* number:

```
    SELECT TOP 10  *  
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (BULK 'path_to_file.csv',  
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        HEADER_ROW = true)
    WITH
    (   
        your_column_name_1 varchar(50) 1
        your_column_name_4 varchar(50) 4
    ) 
    AS rows
```

Comment: I think column-name override only works if you specify the first ordinal as well?  Otherwise I was getting NULLs returned.  So it looks like, if you specify a column name that does not exist and not use an ordinal, you get a NULL.  So I think your first example needs the ordinal too.

Comment: Without ordinals, it will only work if you specify *all* the columns from the file.  The first example is trying to describe that case :). If you skip one or more columns, you have to provide ordinals for all of them then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the names with a subquery / derived table, eg

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'some path',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION ='2.0',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    ) AS [result]
) x ( col1, col2 )
```

This is more compact than the `WITH` clause I think, where you have to specify all columns, all data-types and all ordinals as far as I can tell.  Unfortunately it won't let you put the column list after the `[result]` alias.